# What is manual installation of required libraries and applications?

Tags: 14.04

A treasured friend has suddenly passed away. I'm left trying to recover and burn to DVD digital video of his wedding for his parents and bride, possibly the last new images his family will ever see of him. But I am new to Ubuntu and no longer have windows and I'm having trouble with my JVC Everio HDD Camcorder and Brasero disc burner. I am not a power-user and the funeral service is tomorrow... please can someone explain... what does this message mean, what is Ubuntu asking me to do? Thank you so much.

```
All required applications and libraries are not installed.
Please install the following manually and try again:
mplex (GStreamer plugin)
avenc_mp2 (GStreamer plugin)
avenc_ac3 (GStreamer plugin)
avenc_mpeg2video (GStreamer plugin)
dvdauthor (application).”
```

**New edit:**
I'm sorry I don't know what I am doing in Ubuntu as yet but thank you for 
your time. The kindly given suggestions prompted the computer to communicate to me two new error messages:

```
'An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click menu or 
apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong. The error message was: 'Error: 
BrokenCount >0.' This usually means that your installed packages have unmet 
dependencies.'


'Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another 
process using it?' 
...
```

I tried, neither a right-click nor the search thingy at the top of the ubuntu toolbar has revealed for me this Package Manager program. I've been using this black box appearing application called terminal... I hope this is the correct one... are there multiple? I closed all the video applications that were open and it still says the same.

Comment: Run the command `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras` in a terminal and try again, see here for why https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install dvdauthor libmplex2-2.1-0` . That should knock out two of those.  I can't seem to find `avenc` yet though

Answer (score 2):

Thank the entire Ubuntu community so much for the online help it really meant a lot. After some more searching I found a way to make it work for me in this post http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1059889 it turns out I only needed to rename my .MOD files to .MPG in order to burn to DVD using Brasero, and the disk created works in my regular DVD player.